# Remove all text from last dot in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

I have a file named `test.txt` which has:

```
abc.cde.ccd.eed.12345.5678.txt
abcd.cdde.ccdd.eaed.12346.5688.txt
aabc.cade.cacd.eaed.13345.5078.txt
abzc.cdae.ccda.eaed.29345.1678.txt
abac.cdae.cacd.eead.18145.2678.txt
aabc.cdve.cncd.ened.19945.2345.txt
```

If I want to remove everything beyond the first `.` like:

```
cde.ccd.eed.12345.5678.txt
cdde.ccdd.eaed.12346.5688.txt
cade.cacd.eaed.13345.5078.txt
cdae.ccda.eaed.29345.1678.txt
cdae.cacd.eead.18145.2678.txt
cdve.cncd.ened.19945.2345.txt
```

Then I will do

```
for i in `cat test.txt`; do echo ${i#*.}; done
```

but If I want to remove everything after the last `.` like:

```
abc.cde.ccd.eed.12345.5678
abcd.cdde.ccdd.eaed.12346.5688
aabc.cade.cacd.eaed.13345.5078
abzc.cdae.ccda.eaed.29345.1678
abac.cdae.cacd.eead.18145.2678
aabc.cdve.cncd.ened.19945.2345
```

what should I do?

Comment: See [BASH FAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for the correct way to read a file line-by-line. Don't use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} NF--' file
```

In case there are no empty lines, this works. It sets input and output field separators to the dot `.`. Then, decreases the number of fields in one, so that the last one is kept out. Then it performs the default `awk` action: `{print $0}`, that is, print the line.

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' file
```

This catches the last block of `.` + `text` + `end of line` and replaces it with nothing. That is, it removes it.

With `rev` and `cut`:

```
rev file | cut -d'.' -f2- | rev
```

`rev` reverses the line, so that `cut` can print from the 2nd word to the end. Then, `rev` back to get the correct output.

With `bash`:

```
while ISF= read -r line
do
  echo "${line%.*}"
done < file
```

This perform a string operation consisting in replacing the shortest match of `.*` from the end of the variable `$line` content.

With `grep`:

```
grep -Po '.*(?=\.)' file
```

Look-ahead to print just what is before the last dot.

All of them return:

```
abc.cde.ccd.eed.12345.5678
abcd.cdde.ccdd.eaed.12346.5688
aabc.cade.cacd.eaed.13345.5078
abzc.cdae.ccda.eaed.29345.1678
abac.cdae.cacd.eead.18145.2678
aabc.cdve.cncd.ened.19945.2345
```